# How to parallelize row dataframe computations with dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dask

I have a dataframe like the following one:

| index | paper_id | title | embedding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000a0fc8bbef80410199e690191dc3076a290117 | PfSWIB, a potential chromatin regulator for va... | [-0.21326999, -0.39155999, 0.18850000, -0.0664... |
| 1 | 000affa746a03f1fe4e3b3ef1a62fdfa9b9ac52a | Correlation between antimicrobial consumption ... | [-0.23322999, -0.27436000, -0.10449000, -0.536... |
| 2 | 000b0174f992cb326a891f756d4ae5531f2845f7 | Full Title: A systematic review of MERS-CoV (M... | [0.26385999, -0.07325000, 0.03762100, -0.12043... |

Where the "embedding" column is a np.array() of some length, whose elements are floats. I need to compute the cosine similarity between every pair of paper_id, and my aim is trying to parallelize it since many of these computations are independent of each other. I thought dask delayed objects would be efficient for this purpose:

The code of my function is:

```
@dask.delayed
def cosine(vector1, vector2):
    
    #one can use only the very first elements of the embeddings, i.e. lengths of the embeddings must coincide
    num_elem = min(len(vector1), len(vector2))
    
    vec1_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector1[0:num_elem])
    vec2_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector2[0:num_elem])
    try:
        cosine = np.vdot(vector1[0:num_elem], vector2[0:num_elem])/(vec1_norm*vec2_norm)
    except:
        cosine = 0.
    
    return cosine
```

```
delayed_cosine_matrix = np.eye(len(cosine_df),len(cosine_df))

for x in range(1, len(cosine_df)):
    for y in range(x):
        delayed_cosine_matrix[x,y] = cosine(cosine_df.embedding[x], cosine_df.embedding[y])
        delayed_cosine_matrix[y,x] = cosine(cosine_df.embedding[x], cosine_df.embedding[y])
```

This however returns an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Delayed'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-90cefc4986d5> in <module>
      3 for x in range(1, len(cosine_df)):
      4     for y in range(x):
----> 5         delayed_cosine_matrix[x,y] = cosine(cosine_df.embedding[x], cosine_df.embedding[y])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Moreover, I would stress the fact that I have chosen np.eye() since the cosine of a vector with itself returns one, as well as I would like to exploit the symmetry of the operator, i.e.

> cosine(x,y) == cosine(y,x)

Is there a way to efficiently do and parallelize it, or am I totally out of scope?

EDIT: I'm adding a small snippet code that reproduces the columns and layout needed for the dataframe (i.e. only "embeddings" and the index)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

emb_lengths = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size = 100)
elements = [np.random.random(size = (1,x)) for x in emb_lengths ]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(elements, columns = ['embeddings'])
my_df.embeddings = my_df.embeddings.apply(lambda x: x[0])
my_df
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, if you provide some Python-parsable form of the table you shared (e.g. using `df.to_dict()`), it might help people reproduce your issue more easily.

Comment: what do you expect your out to be? a numpy array? https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_delayed may help?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers. I added a code snippet to recreate the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I do expect my output to be a symmetric np.matrix once the two loops over the indices are computed. I simply wanted to understand whether the two loops could be parallelized somehow since computations are essentially independent of each other.